# Talend components to obtain files from any https server (one drive, g drive and sharepoint)

Tags: talend

I am trying to use Talend components to access a bunch of files from any http server. First I tried using the tHTTPRequest to access a a file from my google drive.

[tHTTPRequest component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1utJ4.png)

After I ran the job, the response content got stored into a file as html code of the login page. Does this mean the username and password didn't work?

[load.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JREqB.png)

How to go about this without using the googledrive component? If not possible how to retrieve files from one drive or sharepoint?

Comment: Please read about the APIs for each of those services and how to authenticate with them. You can't just pass a username and password, they most likely use OAuth authentication.

Comment: Yes, i agree. But what component do we use in Talend? For google drive the, the tGoogleDriveConnection component works. What component do we use for other sites?

Comment: Talend has components for Box and Dropbox. Maybe there are community components for other services, try searching for them.

Comment: I could use the tHTTPClient component to retrieve files right?